# dplyr join without increasing row count

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two different data frames A and B.

The A table features

```
ID  Total Sum
```

The B table features multiple entries for each ID and a various attributes

```
ID  Attribute 1  Attribute 2  Attribute 3
```

I would like to Join A to B returning only one row from the B next to my total column on the A table but when doing so I end up with repeated ID values on Table A.

I try all the joins on the dplyr cheat sheet but I can't get it working.

Below the reproducible example and desired output

Table A

```
TableA<-data.frame(ID=c("KM001","KM002","KM003"))

TableB<-data.frame(ID=c("KM001","KM002","KM003","KM002","KM003","KM002","KM003"),score=c("100", "20", "10", "20", "10", "20", "10"), tieColor=c("blue", "red", "blue", "orange", "purple", "black", "pink"),rainyDay=c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"))
```

Desired Output

```
Desired<-data.frame(ID=c("KM001","KM002","KM003"),TotalScoreSum=c("100","60","30"),tieColor=c("blue", "red", "blue"),rainyDay=c("yes", "yes", "yes"))
```

If you think excel it will be the equivalent of doing a sumif on id From table A and B and TotalScoreSum and for the other two "tieColor" and "rainyDay" attributes a vlookup retrieving only the first match on each column.

Comment: That is always going to happen when joining, since the joining method does not 'know' which row to select from B. You should specify which row to join by taking a subset from B with only on row per ID. Then join that subset to A.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and desired output

Comment: Sorry about that I had include a reproducible and desired output now

Comment: It seems to be an aggreation problem rather than a joining problem. You could create your expected output like this: `TableB %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(score = sum(as.numeric(as.character(score))), tieColor = first(tieColor), rainyDay = first(rainyDay))`. Note that your "score" column is `factor`

Comment: Thanks this does it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks the problem was an aggregation one. docendo discimus solution works fine.

```
TableB %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(score = sum(as.numeric(as.character(score))), tieColor = first(tieColor), rainyDay = first(rainyDay))
```